# Only show one part of interacting x variable in x-axis labels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I am plotting interacting variables on the x-axis of a ggplot, for example as below. Since I am using a fill color to indicate one of the values (here, `variable`), I would only like my x-axis labels to display the other variable (here, `study_day`). I can't specify a manual scale (`scale_x_discrete(labels = c('1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2')`) because my `study_day` values may vary in each facet, as in this example. How do I indicate to only label the x-axis with `study_day`?

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(variable = rep(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 8),
                 study_day = rep(c('1', '2'), 12),
                 ID = rep(c('W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'), 6),
                 value = rnorm(24))

ggplot(df, aes(interaction(variable, study_day), value))+
  geom_point(shape = 21, aes(fill = variable))+
  facet_wrap(~ID, scales = 'free')
```

[image]

Comment: Use `scale_x_discrete`. You can give it a labeler function, such as `labels = function(x) stringr::str_extract(x, "\\d+")`, which will extract the number out of "A.1", "B.1", etc

Comment: How about using dodging instead of an interaction variable?  So put `study_day` on the x axis and then use `position = position_dodge(width = .5)` (with whatever width you like) in `geom_point`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a `make_labels()` function that extracts the study day from the labels ggplot2 generates:

```
library(stringr)

make_labels <- function(labels) {
  result <- str_split(labels, "\\.")
  unlist(lapply(result, function(x) x[2]))
}

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(variable = rep(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 8),
                 study_day = rep(c('1', '2'), 12),
                 ID = rep(c('W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'), 6),
                 value = rnorm(24))

ggplot(df, aes(interaction(variable, study_day), value))+
  geom_point(shape = 21, aes(fill = variable))+
  facet_wrap(~ID, scales = 'free') +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = make_labels, name = "study day")
```

[image]